# Como que eu consigo criar um arquivo .bat através de um arquivo .bat?

Tags: batch

**Como que eu consigo criar um arquivo .bat através de um arquivo .bat? Ou qualquer arquivo?**

Estou criando um tipo de jogo e ele tem que criar uma pasta e dentro dessa pasta tem que ter um arquivo .bat ou um arquivo qualquer, só não pode ser .txt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo qualquercoisa > qualquerarquivo.bat
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
::Gerando outro arquivo bat a partir deste
echo  Gerando arquivo NovoBat.bat, Aguarde.
timeout /t 2 >nul
echo @echo off >NovoBat.bat
echo Title Novo .Bat Gerado Com Sucesso>>NovoBat.bat
echo ::envia uma mensagem ao usuario>>NovoBat.bat
echo msg /w /time:5 %username% "Mensagem de Teste. Aguarde 5 Segundos.">>NovoBat.bat
timeout /t 1 >nul
if exist "NovoBat.bat" (Echo Arquivo Criado.) else Echo Erro! Algo deu errado.
pause >nul
```